# Redirect into a brand new page

Tags: asp.net-mvc

I have an attribute, SessionEndAttribute, that checks if the session is alive. It is attached to each action.

If the session has expired, it runs this method:

```
 public override void OnActionExecuting(ActionExecutingContext filterContext) {
   // do logout, clear cookies
   filterContext.Result = new RedirectToRouteResult( .. )
 }
```

But sometimes the response is not a route to a new page (e.g. route "/Account/Login") but just a popup or partial view, which could just be a container div.

So, the question is - how can I always redirect to a new page?

Comment: You have to tell this particular actionfilter to only run for full controller actions and not partial controller actions `[ChildActionOnly]`.  You also have to make sure that all of your AJAX calls use the `[ChildActionOnly]` calls.  It's been a little while since I've touched MVC, but this is the path I'd go down. there [should be a boolean property in the context](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8060979/in-asp-net-mvc-3-what-is-filtercontext-ischildaction), `isChildAction` or `ChildActionOnly` to help you out.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to tell this particular actionfilter to only run for full controller actions and not partial controller actions `[ChildActionOnly]`.

You also have to make sure that all of your AJAX calls use the `[ChildActionOnly]` calls.

there [should be a boolean property in the context](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8060979/in-asp-net-mvc-3-what-is-filtercontext-ischildaction), `IsChildAction` to help you out.

As Andriy pointed out in the comment, you should also check and make sure the `filterContext` isn't executing an AJAX request, using `ifilterContext.HttpContext.Request.IsAjaxRequest()`

Usage:

```
public override void OnActionExecuting(ActionExecutingContext filterContext) {
   // do logout, clear cookies
   if (!filterContext.IsChildAction && !filterContext.HttpContext.Request.IsAjaxRequest()) {
       filterContext.Result = new RedirectToRouteResult( .. )
   }
}
```

Comment: if (!filterContext.IsChildAction && !filterContext.HttpContext.Request.IsAjaxRequest()) - this would be better

Comment: @AndriyZakharko You're absolutely right; I completely forgot about the `IsAjaxRequest()` method.