# Run code every time a page loads

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4, pageload

So I've come to understand that MVC doesn't really have a forms `PageLoad`event equivalency so where do I put a code that I would like to execute every time a page loads? I'd like to check for a cookie.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Put it in the Constructor of the MVC Controller.

Or like this:

```
protected override void OnActionExecuting(ActionExecutingContext filterContext)
{
    base.OnActionExecuting(filterContext);
    // check for cookies!
}
```

Comment: Oh, it's that easy? Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

I think this might fire for every action on the page if there are multiple actions on the page (for example partial views).

If you only want it to fire once you many need to check for

```
filterContext.IsChildAction
```

Like this

```
        protected override void OnActionExecuting(ActionExecutingContext filterContext) {
            if (filterContext.IsChildAction) return;

            // check for cookies!
        }
```

Mentioned here

[In ASP.NET MVC 3, what is filterContext.IsChildAction?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8060979/in-asp-net-mvc-3-what-is-filtercontext-ischildaction)