# Child actions are not allowed to perform redirect actions exception on filter added to Global Filters

Tags: c#, model-view-controller, filter, authorization

I am trying to implement a cross-cutting authorize attribute, but I keep getting an exception -

```
Exception: Child actions are not allowed to perform redirect actions
```

Here is my code:

```
public class FilterConfig
{
    public static void RegisterGlobalFilters(GlobalFilterCollection filters)
    {
        filters.Add(new MyAuthorizeAttribute(new List<string>(), new List<string>()));
    }
}

public class MyAuthorizeAttribute : AuthorizeAttribute
{
    public MyAuthorizeAttribute(IEnumerable<string> permittedRoles = null, IEnumerable<string> permittedUsers = null)
    {
        if (permittedRoles != null) Roles = string.Join(",",permittedRoles);
        if (permittedUsers != null) Users = string.Join(",",permittedUsers);
    }

    protected override void HandleUnauthorizedRequest(AuthorizationContext filterContext)
    {
        filterContext.Result =
            new RedirectToRouteResult(new RouteValueDictionary
            {
                {"controller", "NotAuthorized"},
                {"action", "Index"}
            });
    }
}
```

Is there anything I can do that will allow me to continue using `MyAuthorizeAttribute` as a global filter?

Comment: Good signpost-post question , also I don't think you needed separate answer for it.

Comment: I see nothing wrong with your question/self-answer. I still think it is duplicate as linked [answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/8061184/477420) covers how to do that (in a way that is simpler than shown in your answer) as well as explaining meaning of both "child action" and the check itself.

Comment: I'm not sure... "And if you wish(or do not wish) to do some specific stuff when the action being executed is a child action, you inspect filterContext.IsChildAction property." feels like exact answer to your question.

Comment: @AlexeiLevenkov: I just took a look at these two questions and they look like completely distinct questions. This question is asking why he is getting an *exception*. The other one is asking what is a `ChildAction`. I'm going to vote to reopen on the grounds that they are sufficiently distinct and different questions.

Comment: C Bauer as I've said I think it is good question (and sufficiently unique from search point of view) so worth keeping as duplicate, just answer part was not strictly necessary (but definitely not wrong). So I'd not delete it. Alternatively you can update to spin it in in a way @MikeBantegui read the question - edit/comment and I'll retract my vote if you plan to change it (you'll probably will have to come up with different answer so :)) .

Comment: Hi Alexei, I've changed the title to reflect the issue correctly. However, I'm going to delete the back-and-forth comments above because they are meta and not related to the question but to the moderation concern.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add the following snippet to the beginning of `HandleUnauthorizedRequest`:

```
if (filterContext.IsChildAction)
{
     return;
}
```

This will abort the redirect for child actions.

Alternately, you can disable the attribute for all controllers called only as children using `[AllowAnonymous]`. It can also be used to decorate your 'not authorized' controller to stop the redirect.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/help/self-answer